Error in calculate the date and time ParameterRang ( Start - End ) in Devepress XtraReport
Error in calculate the date and time parameter rang (Start - End) in Devepress XtraReport.
Error when trying to populate the datasource. The following exception was thrown:

Error trying to execute an SQL query 'select>
"OM_Invoice". "OM_InvoiceID", "OM_Invoice". "IDNumber", "OM_Invoice". "CallDirection", "OM_Invoice". "CallerName", "OM_Invoice". "MobileNo", "OM_Invoice". "CALLDATE", "OM_Invoice". "CALLTIME", "OM_Invoice". "CALLDURATION", "OM_Invoice". "LAT", "OM_I... from "dbo". "OM_Invoice" "OM_Invoice"
where (("OM_Invoice". "CALLDATE" >= @DateRang_Start) and ("OM_Invoice". "CALLDATE" <= @DateRang_End) and ("OM_Invoice". "CALLTIME" >= @TimeRang_Start) and ("OM_Invoice". "CALLTIME" <= @TimeRang_End))' with parameters: @DateRang_Start(DateTime) = 09/10/2024 12:00:00
@DateRang_End(DateTime) = 09/10/2024 12:00:00 @TimeRang_Start(DateTime) = 09/10/2024 12:00:00 @TimeRang_End(DateTime) = 09/10/2024 12:00:00.
Error: The data types time and datetime are incompatible in the greater than or equal to operator.

Code:
SqlConn.ConnectionString = "Server=ACCOUNTANT;database=xxxxxxx;User ID=xx;Password=xxxxxxxxx"
        If SqlConn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            SqlConn.Close()
        End If

        SqlConn.Open()
        '=================

        Dim report As New XtraReport1

        'Filter By Date ( Start - End ):
        report.Parameters("DateRang_Start").Value = dtDateStart.EditValue
        report.Parameters("DateRang_End").Value = dtDateEnd.EditValue


        'Filter By Time ( Start - End ) :
        report.Parameters("TimeRang_Start").Value = dtTimeStart.EditValue
        report.Parameters("TimeRang_End").Value = dtTimeEnd.EditValue

        '--------------------------------
        DocumentViewer1.DocumentSource = report
        report.CreateDocument()
        report.RequestParameters = False
        '----------------
        SqlConn.Close()

Devexpress XtraReport Send Query Filter by Date and Time Rang
My Source Code Download  Link
Source Code
Database Script Download Link
Database Script With Simple Data

The issue is that you are comparing a date with a time. It can be seen in your error message:

("OM_Invoice". "CALLTIME" <= @TimeRang_End))'
@TimeRang_End(DateTime) = 09/10/2024 12:00:00

I guess don't want to compare CALLTIME with 09/10/2024 12:00:00. The CALLTIME field is time only, so choose a different field which contains the entire date and time. Your parameter TimeRang_End which is a datetime should probably contain a time as well.
